usepackage comment: conditional output inside environment
I'm using package comment in my projects with great success.
Recently I tried to define conditional output inside a tabularx environment, to no avail.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{row1only}
\excludecomment{row2only}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xc}
\begin{row1only}
Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2 \\
\end{row1only}
\begin{row2only}
Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2 \\
\end{row2only} 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}

Any idea how to make this work?
Or is there any other package that allows conditional output inside a tabularx environment?

not directly related but \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc} is wrong, there has to be at least one X for tabularx

Thanks for pointing that out, corrected this in my question meanwhile.

personally I'd just use \rowA{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2 \\}\rowB{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2 \\} and define \rowA and \rowB to be \newcommand\rowA[1]{} or \newcommand\rowA[1]{#1} depending on whether you want to use it or not

This ain't going to work for a quite interesting couple of reasons:

\excludecomment{foo} makes foo a verbatim-like environment that throws away its input instead of typesetting it;
tabularx reads the entire content of the environment feeding it as an argument to a command.

Unfortunately, it's (almost) impossible to have verbatim text in the argument to a command.
The package cprotect allows for overcoming this limitation, but my test shows that \cprotEnv doesn't work with tabularx (apparently, \cprotEnv only works with environments that don't take arguments).
Using a command may solve the problem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\YN}{mm}% Yes No
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnT \g_deininger_maybe_seq {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\activate}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_deininger_maybe_seq {#1}
 }
\seq_new:N \g_deininger_maybe_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\activate{1,3}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xc}
\YN{1}{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2 \\}
\YN{2}{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2 \\}
\YN{3}{Row3, column 1 & Row2, column 2 \\}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}



Section 3 of the manual of tabularx  says:

The body of the tabularx environment is in fact the argument to a command, and so certain constructions which are not allowed in command arguments (like \verb) may not be used.

Environments defined via \includecomment/\excludecomment are such constructions. (Such environments temporarily change the category-code-régime and rely on stuff being tokenized while the temporary change is in effect. But this is outmanoeuvred when things already got tokenized as argument to a command when those temporary changes were not done yet.)
If you like, you can define macros depending on the includecomment/excludecomment-state either so that they gobble or so that they deliver their argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}

\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\@stopromannumeral{\chardef\@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%===============================================================================
\makeatother

%%===============================================================================
\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\scratchy{mvvvvvvvv}{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\DefineCommentMacro{m}{%
    \scantokens{#2{#1}^^J#3#1#4^^J#5{#1}^^J#6#1#7}%
  }%
  \NewDocumentCommand\ReDefineCommentMacro{m}{%
    \scantokens{#8#1#9^^J#2{#1}^^J#3#1#4^^J#5{#1}^^J#6#1#7}%
  }%
}%
\scratchy{#1}%
         |\begin|%
         |\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{Macro|%
         |}[1]{#1}%|%
         |\end|%
         |\CsNameToCsToken\providecommand{Macro|%
         |}[1]{}%|%
         |\CsNameToCsToken\let{Macro|%
         |}=\relax|%
%%===============================================================================


\begin{document}

\includecomment{row1only}\DefineCommentMacro{row1only}
\includecomment{row2only}\DefineCommentMacro{row2only}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow1only}{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2\\}%
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow2only}{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2\\}%
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\includecomment{row1only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row1only}
\excludecomment{row2only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row2only}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow1only}{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2\\}%
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow2only}{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2\\}%
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\excludecomment{row1only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row1only}
\includecomment{row2only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row2only}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow1only}{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2\\}%
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow2only}{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2\\}%
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\excludecomment{row1only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row1only}
\excludecomment{row2only}\ReDefineCommentMacro{row2only}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xc}
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow1only}{Row1, column 1 & Row1, column 2\\}%
\CsNameToCsToken{Macrorow2only}{Row2, column 1 & Row2, column 2\\}%
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


The following works to some extend, providing you with booleans that you can set to remove row1only and/or row2only "comments".

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l_first_row_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l_first_row_bool % Default first_row to TRUE
\bool_new:N \l_second_row_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l_second_row_bool % Default second_row to TRUE

% User-level interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstrowtrue}{ }{ \bool_set_true:N \l_first_row_bool }
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstrowfalse}{ }{ \bool_set_false:N \l_first_row_bool }
\NewDocumentCommand{\secondrowtrue}{ }{ \bool_set_true:N \l_second_row_bool }
\NewDocumentCommand{\secondrowfalse}{ }{ \bool_set_false:N \l_second_row_bool }

\cs_set_eq:NN \oldtabular \tabular
\cs_set_eq:NN \endoldtabular \endtabular
\tl_new:N \l_tabular_body_text_tl

% Update tabular to eliminate row1only and/or row2only environments
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tabular}{ O{c} m +b }{ }{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tabular_body_text_tl { #3 } % Store tabular environment body in tl

  % Deal with row1only environment
  \bool_if:NTF \l_first_row_bool {
    % true: Remove all instances of \begin{row1only} or \end{row1only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} | \c{end} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} } % \begin{row1only} or \end{row1only}
      { }
      \l_tabular_body_text_tl
  }{% false: Remove everything from \begin{row1only} to \end{row1only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} .* \c{end} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} }
      { }
      \l_tabular_body_text_tl
  }
  % Deal with row2only environment
  \bool_if:NTF \l_second_row_bool {
    % true: Remove all instances of \begin{row2only} or \end{row2only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} | \c{end} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} } % \begin{row2only} or \end{row2only}
      { }
      \l_tabular_body_text_tl
  }{% false: Remove everything from \begin{row2only} to \end{row2only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} .* \c{end} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} }
      { }
      \l_tabular_body_text_tl
  }

  % Set tabular
  \begin{oldtabular}[ #1 ]{ #2 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tabular_body_text_tl % Updated tabular body
  \end{oldtabular}
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \oldtabularx \tabularx
\cs_set_eq:NN \endoldtabularx \endtabularx
\tl_new:N \l_tabularx_body_text_tl

% Update tabularx to eliminate row1only and/or row2only environments
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tabularx}{ m O{c} m +b }{ }{
  % Temporarily restore tabular
  \cs_set_eq:NN \tabular \oldtabular
  \cs_set_eq:NN \endtabular \endoldtabular

  \tl_set:Nn \l_tabularx_body_text_tl { #4 } % Store tabularx environment body in tl

  % Deal with row1only environment
  \bool_if:NTF \l_first_row_bool {
    % true: Remove all instances of \begin{row1only} or \end{row1only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} | \c{end} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} } % \begin{row1only} or \end{row1only}
      { }
      \l_tabularx_body_text_tl
  }{% false: Remove everything from \begin{row1only} to \end{row1only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} .* \c{end} \cB\{ row1only \cE\} }
      { }
      \l_tabularx_body_text_tl
  }
  % Deal with row2only environment
  \bool_if:NTF \l_second_row_bool {
    % true: Remove all instances of \begin{row2only} or \end{row2only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} | \c{end} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} } % \begin{row2only} or \end{row2only}
      { }
      \l_tabularx_body_text_tl
  }{% false: Remove everything from \begin{row2only} to \end{row2only}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN
      { \c{begin} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} .* \c{end} \cB\{ row2only \cE\} }
      { }
      \l_tabularx_body_text_tl
  }

  \begin{oldtabularx}{ #1 }[ #2 ]{ #3 }
    \tl_use:N \l_tabularx_body_text_tl
  \end{oldtabularx}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\firstrowtrue % Keep row1only
\secondrowfalse % Remove row2only

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  (0, 1) & (0, 2) \\
  \begin{row1only}
    \hline
    (1, 1) & (1, 2) \\
  \end{row1only}
  \begin{row2only}
    \hline
    (2, 1) & (2, 2) \\
  \end{row2only}
  \hline
  (3, 1) & (3, 2) \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\firstrowfalse % Remove row1only
\secondrowtrue % Keep row2only

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | c | X | }
  \hline
  (0, 1) & (0, 2) \\
  \begin{row1only}
    \hline
    (1, 1) & (1, 2) \\
  \end{row1only}
  \begin{row2only}
    \hline
    (2, 1) & (2, 2) \\
  \end{row2only}
  \hline
  (3, 1) & (3, 2) \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

Identification of \begin{.}...\end{.} is done using regular expressions. It has not been tested extensively.
